# Jade from external source

Tags: node.js, pug

I want to parse Jade coming from a database. Like from a blog post, where the body is in Jade. Right now I can parse HTML from Jade using:

```
!= post.body
```

It works for HTML, but doesn't for Jade. Is there a way to parse the Jade from an external source?

Comment: It's hard to guess what you are trying to do with the limited information you posted. For example you say: "Currently I'm using this for HTML" and then show a piece of jade syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to compile text-string as Jade template (post body from database):

```
// node.js
// https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/#a5
var jade = require('jade');
var template = 'h1 Hi';
var options = {};

var htmlFunc = jade.compile(template, options);
var locals = {};
var html = htmlFunc(locals);

// now you can pass `html` to your blog post layout.
```

---

You can compile Jade string within a template. That's odd, but anyway:

```
h1!= require('jade').compile('span Hi')();
```